# What does `... -> t a ->...` mean in type signature in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

In the sign signature of the functions `all` and `any`, I see this:

```
Prelude> :t all 
all :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Bool
Prelude> :t any
any :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Bool
```

However, what does `... -> t a ->...` mean ?

Isn't both `t` and `a` a type variable ? if so, what does the juxtapositions of two type variable mean in Haskell ?

Comment: `t` is a typeconstructor with a parameter. For example `Maybe`, if `a` is then `Int`, then the type is a `Maybe Int`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Well, that makes sense. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: The most famous foldable `t` is `[]`. Just pretend that `t a` is `[a]`, except it is a bit more general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Isn't both t and a a type variable? if so, what does the juxtapositions of two type variable mean in Haskell?

Like a *data* constructor can take *parameters* (for example `Just`), a *type* constructor can take parameters as well, these parameters are then types. For example the `Maybe` type constructor takes a type parameter (for example `Int`), and then is a type `Maybe Int`.

One can for example use a list `[]` to store elements, but there is still a type parameter to be resolved: the type of objects the list will store. `[] Int` or `[Int]` is then a list of `Int`s.

Now `Foldable` types are types that can be folded. For example a list `[]` is a `Foldable` (note that we use `[]`, not `[a]` or `[Int]`) as well as a `Maybe`, or for example a `Tree`. Most "collections" of elements are `Foldable`s, although types that are not collections can be `Foldable`s and vice versa.

The [**`all :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Bool`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:all) and [**`any :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Bool`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:any) are functions that can operate on `Foldable`s. The advantage is thus that we can write `all` and `any` to operate on a list of `a`s (so `[a]`), but a `Maybe a` can be used as well: you can see `Maybe` as a type that is a collection that either contains *no* elements (`Nothing`), or exactly *one* element (`Just x` with `x` the element). We can for example write:

```
Prelude> all id Nothing
True
Prelude> all id (Just True)
True
Prelude> all id (Just False)
False
Prelude> all id []
True
Prelude> all id [True]
True
Prelude> all id [False]
False
Prelude> all id [False, True]
False
Prelude> all id [True, True]
True
```

The `all` thus can work on lists, `Maybe`s, but a lot of other types as well.